# Finding nearest neighbour given fields in a few dimensions

Tags: algorithm, knn, kdtree

I've a 5 dimension point set, and I want to find the point nearest to an incomplete query point.
An example query point is (X, X, 34, 45, 66).

I was wondering if there is any algorithm, which uses Euclidean distance measure, considers only the dimensions for which the values are defined (happens to be 3rd, 4th and 5th in example query above) to give the nearest neighbour?

I tried to play with kd-tree, but realised that the knn search with it would work only once you reach the 'leaf' node (and start moving upwards from there with balls within bound test). With missing values for some dimensions, it won't be possible to reach a leaf node, right? Then I'll need to traverse in both directions when such a split node is encountered when a missing dimension is the discriminant, and I'll end up with several leaf nodes. So if I am not wrong, I'll need to run many knn searches from each of these nodes, am I right?

Please give more detailed explanation that just a yes/no.

Comment: In a kd-tree, every tree level corresponds to one of your dimensions. Typically, you can decide for one of the branches on that level, to limit the search space. If you have an `X` on that dimension, you'll just need to search in all branches for that level.

Comment: @Heuster, that's what I have mentioned as well. I would like to know if there's some better way, or a different data structure altogether that helps me solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your own suggestion.

Comment: @Heuster, if we agree on the approach that you and I have suggested, wouldn't search for nearest neighbor become expensive as the missing dimensions increase? I understand that with many missing dimensions, we will need to start from many leaf nodes, and that may result in the computation complexity close to O(n), right? I have a feeling this is not going to scale if missing dimensions increase.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that... the leaf node you end up with is just a *first candidate* for the nearest neighbor. After that you traverse up the tree again and ignore all branches for which you know for sure that all nodes in there are not your nearest neighbor. I would just propose to pick an arbitrary branch for an `X` dimension to end up with your first candidate. It can most likely be shown that the time complexity is `O(n)` worst case anyway.

Comment: @Heyster, I am not sure if choosing any arbitrary branch will give you the correct result. Think of case where the final candidate contains the nearest neighbor, and no overlap of the Balls within Bound test happens. In such a scenario, the traversal up the tree is not going to happen, and it is obviously possible that the first candidate may not be the correct solution.